# How to create "prefabs" of a certain class in Java

Tags: java, class

I have a robot class with different paramters : `maxHealth`, `maxShield` and `attack`.
I'd like to make different "prefabs" of this class : just a robot but with some specific value for the variables above.
For example an `Assault` would would be a robot with `500 maxHealth` and `300 maxShield`, an assault **has no extra function/variable, just the robot's one**.
The easiest way to do it would be to do another class like this :

```java
public class Assault extends Robot{
  public Assault(){
      super(Constants.ASSAULT_HEALTH,Constants.ASSAULT_SHIELD);
  }
}
```

or a custom constructor for robot :

```java
    public Robot(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case ("ASSAULT"):
                health = 500;
                shield = 300;
            case ("MACHINE GUN"):
                health = 1000;
                shield = 600;
            default: 
                health = 200;
                shield = 400;

        }
    }
```

or a function inside robot:

```java
public void setAssault(){
   this.health = 500
   this.shield = 300
}
```

But I think there are better solution, thanks for your help !

[EDIT]
So in comments you suggest to use a `factory` class like this ?

```java
public class RobotFactory {
    public static Robot createAssault(int posX, int posY){
        return new Robot(posX, posY, 500, 300);
    }
}
```

Comment: Factory pattern?

Comment: Exactly, create a static factory method for each type of robot.

Comment: Just edited with my factory class, can you confirm that it's what you were talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I would do what you want like that:

Define an enum of the different robot types. Add the variable parameters as parameters of the enum:

```
public enum RobotType {
  ASSAULT(500, 300),
  DEFENCE(900, 600);

  private int health;
  private int shield;

  private RobotType(int health, int shield) {
    this.health = health;
    this.shield = shield;
  } 

  public int getHealth() {
    return health;
  }

  public in getShield() {
    return shield;
  }

}
```

And then have a more generic factory method:

```
public static Robot createAssault(int posX, int posY, RobotType type){
   return new Robot(posX, posY, type.getHealth(), type.getShield());
}
```

You call this like that:

```
RobotFactory.createAssault(0, 0, RobotType.ASSAULT);
```

Having these constants associated with enum values allows for easy reuse and association with specific type.

Comment: Yes that was the kind of structure I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `Builder` pattern instead of `Factory` - in my opinion this approach let you more efficiently support the situation when you will e.g. add additional property to robot or e.g. you'd like to force user to always provide some additional property. If you will have static methods then every change in object's constructor will cause changes in all factory methods and the additional input will modify the methods signatures. If you will keep your 'prefabs' as builder instances you will need to modify only `Builder` implementation or add additional logic in a place where you are getting the input from user

Basically what I'm suggesting is to prepare something like

```
class RobotBuilder {
    private int health;
    private int shield;

    public RobotBuilder setHealth(int health) {
        this.health = health;
        return this;
    }

    // all other setters etc... 

    public Robot build() {
        return new Robot(this.health, this.shield);
    }
}

// ...

RobotBuilder assaultPrefab = new RobotBuilder().setHealth(500).setShield(300);

// create assault:
Robot assault = assaultPrefab.build();

// e.g. getting input from user:
int bonusShield = whatIsYourBonusShield();

assaultPrefab.setShield(assaultPrefab.getShield() + bonusShield); 

// notice that you are modifying just the specific instance of prefab object 
// in this place, if you would modify factory method you would change factory's API 
// or need to add additional method when there is bonus etc...
```

You can create such prefab "in place" or define it in some kind of provider/singleton/service - imho this is very flexible way to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use the abstract factory pattern or the factory method pattern to achieve this.

I think the best is to use an abstract factory because it allows you to change the way object are created later on in the production.
For now, i will show a trivial implementation of the abstract factory, with no interfaces and I'll keep it simple.
If you want more, you can find info about that pattern [here](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory)

So, you'll need an abstract class (i.e. a class that cannot be instantiated, but only used to call static methods):

```
public abstract class RobotFactory {
    public static Robot createAssault(){
       return new Robot(<assaultParams>)
    }

    public static Robot createMachineGun(){
       return new Robot(<machineGunParams>)
    }
}
```

The use it in you code like:

```
 ...
 Robot myAssaultRobot = RobotFactory.createAssault();
 ...
```

Later on in production, you could create an interface that exposes those methods and implement that interface in the abstract factory.
This will allow you to change the factory, hence creating different robot of the same type but in different ways.